# How to change only selected element css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have products table, It loads different html page by product id. Now I want to highlight the selected(selected by a element) table row. I'm using a function to know what unique id it has.

```
 function Tooted(str) {
        var url="tooted.php?q="+str;
        if (str == "") {
            $("#txtHint").html("");
            return;
        } else {
            $("#txtHint").load(url);
        }



    $("#tellimus"+str).on('click',function(){
        if(str!=str){

        $(this).css({'background-color':'white'})
    }
    else{$(this).css({'background-color':'#6495ED'})}
        });

    }
```

It opens the selected html page like this

```
<td>'.$r["id"].' <a id="link" nohref style="cursor:pointer;" onClick="Tooted(\''.$r["id"].'\')">Tooted</a></td>
```

I'm selecting each row by unique id like this:

```
<tr class="tellimuz" id=tellimus'.$r["id"].'>
```

Full php/html code:

```
$out .= "\n".'<tr class="tellimuz" id=tellimus'.$r["id"].'>
    <td>'.$r["id"].' <a id="link" nohref style="cursor:pointer;" onClick="Tooted(\''.$r["id"].'\')">Tooted</a></td>
    <td>'.$r["kp"].'</td>
    </tr>';
```

Now as I said I wanted to highlight the table row what is selected by function.
**The backgroud-color change works, BUT I want to only highlight the selected row. Atm every selected row changes background color and dosent change it back to white when it's not selected**

Comment: you use `$r` but in your tag not define `php`

Comment: can you please create a demo on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: share your full code for better result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be missing a closing bracket for your "Tooted" function in your javascript.

You have the same id ("link") for every anchor tag.

You have `(str!=str)` in your code. You're comparing a variable to itself, which will ***ALWAYS*** be equal to itself, so here it's always, ***ALWAYS*** `false`

What your function is actually doing:

When you click a link, it is loading in HTML to your `#txtHint` element. You are then binding another function to the click event for the entire row which essentially toggles the background color.

```
function Tooted(str) {
  var url="tooted.php?q="+str;
  if (str == "") {
    $("#txtHint").html("");
    return;
  } else {
    $("#txtHint").load(url);
  }

  $("#tellimus"+str).on('click',function(){
    if(str!=str){
      $(this).css({'background-color':'white'})
    } else {
      $(this).css({'background-color':'#6495ED'})}
    });
  }
}
```

What (I think) you're trying to do is change one row to your highlighted background color, and the rest to white. Instead of a single-element toggle like you have above, you need to change one to the highlighted color, and the rest to white.

```
function Tooted(str){
  var url = "tooted.php?q="+str;
  if (str == "") {
    $("#txtHint").html("");
    return;
  } else {
    $("#txtHint").load(url);
  }

  //no need to get fancy with IDs, just get closest parent row
  $(this).closest("tr")
    //change this row to your highlight color
    .css({'background-color':'#6495ED'})
    //then get all the other rows and make them white
    .siblings("tr").css({'background-color':'white'})
}
```

If I'm assuming wrong, please clarify your question. Your rendered HTML would be very helpful.